# How to scroll to bottom of a multi-line TextBox?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a web control in which I have a multiple line text box. I'm updating the contents of the text box using a timer_tick event. I want to display the last line of the text box every time the timer_tick event is fired. Can some one help me?

Comment: Show us the code you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, but to get the last line of an ASP.NET TextBox on serverside:

```
Dim lastLine = txt.Text.Split({Environment.NewLine},
                            StringSplitOptions.None).Last
```

On clientside you could get the last line with this javascript:

```
var lines    = input.value.split('\n');
var lastLine = lines[lines.length-1];
```

Your question instead seem to be "[how to scroll asp.net textbox to bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388127/how-to-scroll-asp-net-textbox-to-bottom)"

Handle [`Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.endRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810.aspx) event and scroll the textbox down:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

function EndRequestHandler(sender, args)
{
   if (args.get_error() == undefined)
   {
       var tbox = $get('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>');
       tbox.scrollTop = tbox.scrollHeight;
   }
}
```

Comment: for the chat application I'm creating, As you know I'm using a timer on the text box to pull out messages from the database and to see if a particular user have any messages. I'm writing code in the Timer_Tick event to check the database for every 2 seconds. When this timer is fired the Text box is scrolled to the top automatically for every two seconds. I want to show the bottom line of the text box where I'm displaying a new message to the user.

Comment: @krisch: So your question is instead: How to scroll to bottom of a multiline TextBox?

Comment: yeah, you are correct(should display bottom every time it refreshes)

Comment: I used a similar setIntervel and setTimeout functions on the .ascx page but they are not working... Can you explain me a bit more.

Comment: In the web user control I won't have form tag.. probably is that causing error?

Comment: @krish: see my updated answer and the link to the `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager endRequest Event`. The form is not required since the UserControl will be rendered into the form of it's aspx-page. Notice that this is not codebehind but javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I think the OP was looking for scrolling the text box to the bottom on every update.
I found [this](http://www.stymee.net/?p=45) which helped me.

```
Textbox1.SelectionStart = Textbox1.Text.Length - 1  
Textbox1.ScrollToCaret()
```